# In isabelle, why is this simplification lemma not being substituted?

Tags: isabelle

I'm working through the Isabelle "Programming and Proving" tutorial, and am coming to Ex2.10, where you have to arrive at an equation discribing the number of nodes in an "exploded" tree.

The approach I've taken to this is to create separate expressions for the internal and leaf nodes in the tree, and am working on a proof for the number of internal nodes in the tree, as such:

```
lemma dddq: " a>0 ⟶ (nodes_noleaf (explode a b) = (ptser (a - 1) (2::nat)) + ((2 ^ a) * (nodes_noleaf b)))"
apply(induction a)
apply(simp)
apply(simp add:eeei eeed eeej eeek )
```

and this leaves the proof state as the following:

```
goal (1 subgoal):
 1. ⋀a. 0 < a ⟶ nodes_noleaf (explode a b) = ptser (a - Suc 0) 2 + 2 ^ a * nodes_noleaf b ⟹
     Suc (2 * nodes_noleaf (explode a b)) = ptser a 2 + 2 * 2 ^ a * nodes_noleaf b
```

Now, I also created (and successfully proved) a lemma that should replace the `ptser a 2 + 2 * 2 ^ a * nodes_noleaf b` with `(Suc (2 * ((ptser (a - Suc 0) 2) + 2 ^ a * nodes_noleaf b))))`, as such:

```
lemma eeek: "∀ a b . a>0 ⟶ (((ptser a 2) + 2 * 2 ^ a * nodes_noleaf b) = (Suc (2 * ((ptser (a - Suc 0) 2) + 2 ^ a * nodes_noleaf b))))"
apply(auto)
apply(simp add: ddddd)
done
```

However, adding this to the list of simplifications for the dddq does nothing, and I don't see the reason why.

---

Additional definitions..

```
fun nodes_noleaf:: "tree0 ⇒ nat" where
"nodes_noleaf Tip = 0"|
"nodes_noleaf (Node a b) = (add 1 (add (nodes_noleaf a) (nodes_noleaf b)))"

fun explode:: "nat ⇒ tree0 ⇒ tree0" where
"explode 0 t = t" |
"explode (Suc n) t = explode n (Node t t)"

fun ptser:: "nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat" where
"ptser 0 b = b^0" |
"ptser a b = b^a + (ptser (a - 1) b)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lemma `eeek` is a conditional rewrite rule, because it can only be applied when the simplifier can prove that `a > 0` holds. In your goal state, however, you do not have the assumption `a > 0`. The `0 < a` is a precondition to the induction hypothesis (`-->` binds stronger than `==>`), which is why `simp` does not apply the induction hypothesis either.

Since the question does not contain all the definitions of your goal, it is hard to pinpoint the exact reason. Nevertheless, I suggest to drop the assumption `a > 0` from `dddq` and prove a stronger statement.

A comment on style: Try to use the connectives `!!` and `==>` of the natural deduction framework rather than explicit universal quantifiers and `-->`. The simplifier knows how to convert them back into `!!` and `==>`, but other proof methods do not do this automatically. Thus, using `!!` and `==>` will save you boilerplate proof steps later on.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As it stands, I can't remove the a>0 because some of my other lemmas don't hold for 0.  Particularly a proof that my ptser function (a recursive function that defines a series of powers-of two..). It did have a>(Suc 0) in the implied part of the induction hypothesis before it was removed by the simplifier - I assumed this was because the initial a>0 applied in that context and made it redundant.

Comment: When you do induction over `a`, you get the assumption `Suc a > 0` which holds trivially and is therefore removed. If your statement does not hold for `a = 0`, you probably have to do a case distinction in the induction step whether `a = 0`.

Comment: I was under the impression the simplifier worked explored the full tree of possible simplification paths? In this case, would it not also examine the case with applying the eeek substitution before removing Suc a > 0 ?

Comment: The simplifier follows just one path. It rewrites inner terms before outer terms.
Moreover, `Suc a > 0` would not help in applying `eeek`, because the `a` in `eeek` gets instantiated with `a` from the goal state, not `Suc a`.

Comment: I see the problem - I was getting 0<(Suc a) mentally mixed up with a<(Suc 0). Unfortunately, it looks like fixing it's going to require me to rethink the entire approach. I'm marking this as the correct answer..